# i want to upload image into Google drive and retrieve the image URL from Google drive in android- eclipse ?

Tags: android, image, upload, google-drive-api, resume

i want to upload image into Google drive using android eclipse (let me know if anything good than drive) and retrieve from it for later use . i need to start camera from app and took a pic then it must save (Optional : i don't want to save in external/internal storage) in Google drive or any other good image storage ( need suggestion for this) sites and retrieve to specific persons detail .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use Google Drive Android API? https://developers.google.com/drive/android/